# Numpy with loadtxt

Tags: python, numpy

For the code I am writing, I need to convert a .dat file with a list of numbers and a header into a numpy array. I must then reshape each data array into an 89x125 rectangle. I am having trouble converting the file to each variable that corresponds with the set of values. Any help would be helpful I find using numpy very confusing.

First lines of .dat file:

```
title="velocity" variables = "X/C", "Y/C",
"U","V","Omega","Lamta",zone i=125, j=89, DATAPACKING=POINT 
-0.925333,  2.625333, -0.007452,  0.249024,-2.348774e-01,3.685912e-07  
-0.925333,  2.604000, -0.008238,  0.244324,-2.009359e-02,1.858388e-06  
-0.925333,  2.582667, -0.003536,  0.198775,1.353259e+00,3.546745e-05  
-0.925333,  2.561333, -0.001177,  0.209091,6.279517e-01,2.377224e-05  
-0.925333,  2.540000, -0.013361,  0.157628,2.788983e+00,2.688667e-05  
-0.925333,  2.518667, -0.016351,  0.159980,3.093468e+00,8.040523e-06  
-0.925333,  2.497333, -0.004509,  0.220179,2.561251e+00,9.985430e-06  
-0.925333,  2.476000,  0.000511,  0.213207,1.077752e+00,3.425355e-06  
-0.925333,  2.454667, -0.007348,  0.196955,2.366343e+00,4.243688e-05


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

Uc = 0.16 #m/s
diaPC = 38 #mm
diaOT = 76 #mm
sDis = 4*38 #mm
PIV = 500 #FPS

fname = 'Velocity0241.txt'
dtype1 = np.dtype([('X/C', 'f4'), ('Y/C', 'f4'), ('U', 'f4'), ('V', 'f4')])
data = np.loadtxt(fname, dtype=dtype1, skiprows=2, usecols=(0,1,2,3))
```

I always get this error:

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-f4aaca3e57b3> in <module>
     11 fname = 'Velocity0241.txt'
     12 dtype1 = np.dtype([('X/C', 'f4'), ('Y/C', 'f4'), ('U', 'f4'), ('V', 'f4')])
---> 13 data = np.loadtxt(fname, dtype=dtype1, skiprows=2, usecols=(0,1,2,3))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in loadtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, converters, skiprows, usecols, unpack, ndmin, encoding, max_rows)
   1157         # converting the data
   1158         X = None
-> 1159         for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
   1160             if X is None:
   1161                 X = np.array(x, dtype)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in read_data(chunk_size)
   1085 
   1086             # Convert each value according to its column and store
-> 1087             items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
   1088 
   1089             # Then pack it according to the dtype's nesting

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1085 
   1086             # Convert each value according to its column and store
-> 1087             items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
   1088 
   1089             # Then pack it according to the dtype's nesting

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in floatconv(x)
    792         if '0x' in x:
    793             return float.fromhex(x)
--> 794         return float(x)
    795 
    796     typ = dtype.type

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-0.925333,'
```

Comment: The default delimiter in `loadtxt` is white space.  It looks like your file uses commas.  That said, I'm not sure `loadtxt` is the right reader for this file format.  `loadtxt` is design to parse `csv` files - ones with neat rows and columns of data.

Comment: Make the sure the display of your file sample is right - with clear use of new lines etc.  I considered editing your question, but decided I couldn't tell exactly what it contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding delimiter to your call:

```
In [169]: txt = """title="velocity" variables = "X/C", "Y/C",
     ...: "U","V","Omega","Lamta",zone i=125, j=89, DATAPACKING=POINT 
     ...: -0.925333,  2.625333, -0.007452,  0.249024,-2.348774e-01,3.685912e-07 
     ...: -0.925333,  2.604000, -0.008238,  0.244324,-2.009359e-02,1.858388e-06 
     ...: -0.925333,  2.582667, -0.003536,  0.198775,1.353259e+00,3.546745e-05   
     ...: -0.925333,  2.561333, -0.001177,  0.209091,6.279517e-01,2.377224e-05   
     ...: -0.925333,  2.540000, -0.013361,  0.157628,2.788983e+00,2.688667e-05  
     ...: -0.925333,  2.518667, -0.016351,  0.159980,3.093468e+00,8.040523e-06  
     ...: -0.925333,  2.497333, -0.004509,  0.220179,2.561251e+00,9.985430e-06  
     ...: -0.925333,  2.476000,  0.000511,  0.213207,1.077752e+00,3.425355e-06  
     ...: -0.925333,  2.454667, -0.007348,  0.196955,2.366343e+00,4.243688e-05"""
In [170]: dtype1 = np.dtype([('X/C', 'f4'), ('Y/C', 'f4'), ('U', 'f4'), ('V', 'f
     ...: 4')])
     ...: data = np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines(), dtype=dtype1, skiprows=2, usecols=
     ...: (0,1,2,3),delimiter=',')
In [171]: data
Out[171]: 
array([(-0.925333, 2.625333, -0.007452, 0.249024),
       (-0.925333, 2.604   , -0.008238, 0.244324),
       (-0.925333, 2.582667, -0.003536, 0.198775),
       (-0.925333, 2.561333, -0.001177, 0.209091),
       (-0.925333, 2.54    , -0.013361, 0.157628),
       (-0.925333, 2.518667, -0.016351, 0.15998 ),
       (-0.925333, 2.497333, -0.004509, 0.220179),
       (-0.925333, 2.476   ,  0.000511, 0.213207),
       (-0.925333, 2.454667, -0.007348, 0.196955)],
      dtype=[('X/C', '<f4'), ('Y/C', '<f4'), ('U', '<f4'), ('V', '<f4')])

In [172]: data['X/C']
Out[172]: 
array([-0.925333, -0.925333, -0.925333, -0.925333, -0.925333, -0.925333,
       -0.925333, -0.925333, -0.925333], dtype=float32)
```